# Should it be a Gerund Modifying the Verb or a Past-Tense Verb?

Tags: gerunds

Say I have a sentence like
"The child, realizing the parent's weakness, started coming up with his plan to take his device back from the parent."
I know it should be realizing, not realized. However, I am wondering if someone can give me a better explanation on why it should be realizing.

Comment: It's a gerund-participial clause, but it's not a modifier of "the child". It's a supplement, a loosely attached expression presenting supplementary content.

Comment: "Realizing" and "having realized" both work.  The former gives a greater sense of immediacy.

Comment: @BillJ: If I write "Realising the parent's weakness, the child started...", the part of the sentence before the comma is a gerund-participial clause but modifying " the child" this time. Am I right?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. It will still be a supplementary adjunct, a non-modifying element.

Comment: Oh! Could you please give a example where the gerund-participial clause modifies the noun @BillJ?

Comment: @Userabc "People [living near the incident will have to evacuated]". The bracketed gerund-participial clause modifies "people".

Comment: But as per traditional grammars, in the sentence "Hearing the noise, the boy woke up", 'hearing' is a participle because it modifies the noun 'boy'. Are they wrong then? @BillJ?

Comment: @Userabc Yes, they are wrong. "Hearing" is a gerund participle heading the clause "hearing the noise", which is a supplementary adjunct, not a modifier of "boy".

Comment: @Userabc Here's a PDF link to one of the best books available.You should be able to download it and save it, which will save you about £24 [link](https://hostnezt.com/cssfiles/english/A%20Student's%20Introduction%20To%20English%20Grammar%20by%20Huddleston%20Rodney%20&%20Pullum%20Geoffrey%20(CAMBRIDGE)%20x2.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I moved the comment to the other thread. Never mind! Many thanks, Sir @BillJ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a gerund, it is a participle. The clause is a participial clause modifying "the child". It has no inherent tense (the form is traditionally called the "present participle", but that does not imply present time, it only implies contemperaneity).

A finite verb (whether present or past) cannot fit here syntactically, as it would be another main clause. That would work if you coordinated them: *The child realized the parent's weakness, and started ...*

Both sentences are equally good; yours treats the child's realization as supplementary information, and only has the "starting to come up with the plan" as the main part of the sentence.

Comment: What if I write 'on realising the parent's weakness, the child started....' Is "realising" a gerund now acting as the object of the preposition "on" ?

Comment: Yes. It's worth mentioning that recent grammars do not regard the participle and gerund as distinct, but instead distinguish the kinds of clauses they occur in. A gerund clause can sit in some of the same places as a noun phrase (here, the complement of a preposition). A participial clause can sit in some of the same places as a relative clause.

Comment: Thank you, @Colin Fine. Just one more question before I am clear on this thoroughly. "On seeing the snake, the boy flinched." "Seeing the snake, the boy flinched." It's the gerund clause in the first sentence and participial clause in the second one. Right? And does the first sentence need a comma?

Comment: Those are the traditional labels. I think the parallellism is one reason why recent analyses do not make the distinction (I wrote above that they distinguish the clauses, but I'm not sure they do. I keep meaning to buy my own copy of CGEL).

Comment: As for the comma, I'm not the person to ask. I don't believe in the mystique of the comma. If I would take a new breath group when I spoke it, I would write a comma. In both those sentences I might or I might not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write your sentence using a relative clause.
"The child, ***who was realizing the parent's weakness***, started coming up with his plan to take his device back from the parent." In this sentence the bold part is a relative clause which modifies "the child", and ***"was realising"*** is a verb in Past Continous.

We can make that clause a participle phrase by removing ***"who was"***. Please, note that now "realising" is not a verb, it is a present participle. And ***"realizing the parent's weakness"*** is a present participle phrase.

Comment: Not quite: Non-defining relative clauses are not modifiers, but supplements. They don't combine with the antecedent to form a constituent.

Comment: "who was realising... " here is not an adjective clause but a coordinate clause because it doesn't identify "the child" in any which way. Is that right @BillJ?

Comment: @Userabc No, it's not a coordinate clause, but a supplement.

Comment: This slew of labels is confuddling. Just this last question: "I met Smith, who told me about the incident." Is "who told me about the incident" a supplement or a coordinate clause? @BillJ?

Comment: @Userabc It's a supplement. Coordinate clauses are linked by "and" or "but". You really should buy an up-to-date grammar textbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my confusions, @BillJ. Now that you see where I stand on grammatical matters, I would be indebted if you recommend me a comprehensive and in-vogue grammar book that will help me overcome my faults. Preferably from your shelf. :)

Comment: @Userabc In case you are unable to download and save the PDF I sent you, here is a link to the book on Amazon [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Students-Introduction-English-Grammar/dp/0521612888/ref=asc_df_0521612888/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310865071345&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5029326088309434435&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9045329&hvtargid=pla-469540184534&psc=1&th=1&psc=1)

Comment: Cannot thank you enough, @BillJ. Downloaded the book successfully! :)

Comment: @Userabc It's 312 pages. The book that is over 1000 pages (1800 actually) is CGEL though it is by the same authors, Huddleston & Pullum. It's the one I use for teaching, but you won't need a book that advanced.

Comment: Got it, Sir. Wish I were your student! God bless you!